# JQuery hover & dropdown menus

Tags: jquery, drupal, hover, drop-down-menu

I'm having some trouble with my website's dropdown menu using JQuery.

Basically, what I want to achieve is a simple horizontal dropdown menu with JQuery's hover (in Drupal's DHTML menu module). However, there are some annoyances that I could not fix.

So the main menu and their child `<li>`s are all links. When I click one of the child menu, everything is fine (I got directed to the destination, menu resets to normal unhovered state). But when I click the parent menu, after arriving at the destination, even though the dropdown menu resets back the mouse is still hovering above the link. This results in the dropdown being activated briefly again as I move my mouse away.

What I want is that the dropdown activates only when the mouse enters the element, not when it exits. I've tried separating `.hover()` into `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()`, but this instead results in the dropdown not working at all. Help!

My code is below:

```
 $(li).hover(function(e) {
   Drupal.dhtmlMenu.expandMenu($(li));
 },
 function(e) {
   Drupal.dhtmlMenu.collapseMenu($(li));
 });

 $(li).ready(function(e) {
   Drupal.dhtmlMenu.collapseMenu($(li));
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Nice Menus](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus) module. It will save you from this headache. I've been using it ever since I started with Drupal 3 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely no need to use JavaScript for a simple dropdown menu. See http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-dropdown-menu (CSS3 is used but the basic CSS will work in all browsers). Do it purely in CSS/HTML

Comment: I did use CSS before this (the code remains so dropdown still functions if the client disabled JavaScript). This is just a cosmetic addition which I want to add.